# Undertakings have expired - am I allowed to do whatever I want?

Tags: united-kingdom, family-law

Previously I’ve asked question about undertakings 
- [Non-molestation - undertakings - Legal Aid - is it possible to appeal?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/30652/non-molestation-undertakings-legal-aid-is-it-possible-to-appeal) - whether there is a way to dispute them.

*(what I did not realize at the time, it could have been a plot to obtain Legal Aid)*

Back then agreed to not publish on social media.

These undertakings have now expired.

#### (potentially native) understanding:

1. Someone invites me to the court
2. I say OK, no worries, I will comply.
3. Six months period is gone, am I allowed to publish stuff again?

#### Alternative approach:

1. If someone commits a crime, they are released on probation.
2. Second time they got caught, they are likely to end up in prison.
3. Third time the penalty is even higher.

---

I made a mistake by not challenging the allegations.

Now as the undertakings have expired, am I allowed to do whatever I want?

Or - following the crime example - the next time situation occurs I’m likely to be penalised more?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a court order was made which contained undertakings to the Court. 
Those undertakings were given voluntarily by you to the Court.
The court order would have been sealed (stamped with the Court's seal). 
That gives the undertakings the same status as an injunction. If you do not comply with your undertakings, it's a contempt of court.

It sounds like the undertakings are/were limited in time, to 6 months duration from the date the undertakings were given or from the date the Order was sealed.

If that's the case, then they have lapsed, and you are no longer prevented from doing whatever it was that was restrained by the undertakings.

Because the consequences of getting it are so very serious - you could get yourself locked up - you should send the Undertakings to a lawyer and ask them for advice.

That way you'll avoid misunderstandings.

It all depends on the precise wording of the Court Order.

Comment: You could possibly contact the Court and ask whether the undertakings are still in force. It won't be easy to get through (I hear the courts are more understaffed than ever) but is cheaper than paying a lawyer.

Comment: I hear Courts don't give legal advice. I wouldn't rely on a Court Clerk's opinion if my liberty was at stake - and all the things that flow from that, such as losing my job.

Comment: @tellis: Absolutely courts don't give advice; but here you don't want advice, you want facts. The clerk who sealed the order can't and won't tell you what you should do, but can say whether it is still in force.